# Show that it is impossible to have one-to-one correspondence between a finite set and one of its proper subsets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So I am not exactly sure how to prove this out rigorously. Intuitively it makes sense but I feel like I am misinterpreting it because it seems rather trivial to me. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The (finite) cardinal of the proper subset is strictly lesser than the (finite) cardinal of the finite set.

Comment: And your definition of infinite set is...?

Comment: I think the usual convention is to call a set finite if there is a bijection between the set and some natural number.

Answer (score 5):

If you study axiomatic approach to set theory, then it would be helpful if you post axioms or whatever you have studied so far.

A lot of things about finite sets are easier to prove by induction, because this is at least one way to define finite sets. Here is a sketch of a proof based on this approach:

1) A finite set is by definition the one that is in one-to-one correspondence with a set of natural numbers $\{1,\dots,n\}$ for some $n$, where natural numbers are defined by induction. $n$ is called the cardinality of the set. So, the question becomes whether such a set can be in one-to-one correspondence with its own proper subset.

2) If $n=1$ or $n=2$ you can check (prove) manually that this is not the case.

3) Now, suppose that this cannot be done for all sets with cardinality up to $n\ge 2$. Consider a set with cardinality $n+1$: $A=\{1,\dots,n+1\}$. And let $f$ be a bijection from $A$ onto its proper subset $B$. Since $B$ is a proper subset of $A$, there is some $k$ such that $k\not\in B$. Let $f(k)=m$, then $m\neq k$, and $f$ restricted to $A'=A-\{k\}$ is a bijection such that neither $m$ nor $k$ is in the image, so that it is a bijection from $A'$ onto its proper subset. Now, it remains to notice that $A'$ has cardinality $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a [finite set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set), and let $B$ be a [proper subset](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperSubset.html) of $A$.

The existence of a [one-to-one correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) between the elements of $A$ and $B$ implies that the [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) of $A$ equals the cardinality of $B$:

$$|A| = |B|$$

However, since $B$ is a *proper* subset of $A$, it must have a smaller cardinality. This contradicts $|A| = |B|$, so there can't exist a one-to-one correspondence.

Comment: ...because *A* is finite...

Comment: All you've done is mask your assumption that $|A|<|B|$. This is not helpful (though if you turned it in it may squeak by a tired homework grader).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $A$ is a finite set with cardinal $n\in\mathbb N$ then it's on bijection with the set $\mathbb N_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

To see the desired result we have to prove that 
$$ \text{there's a bijection }\; f\colon \mathbb N_p\rightarrow \mathbb N_n\iff n=p$$
by proving

- $f$ is an injection iff $p\le n$
- $f$ is a surjection iff $p\ge n$.

Comment: Wait, $p \leq n$ doesn't tell you $f$ is injective, $f$ could be constant.

Comment: @DylanYott I mean by the first point:
$$\text{there's an injection }\; f\colon \mathbb N_p\rightarrow \mathbb N_n\iff p\le n$$

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the pigeonhole principle, but I'm not quite sure how one would prove it. Perhaps by induction?

Comment: It would take a slight change in the original statement for the pigeonhole principle to be directly applicable. See my first answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $A\subsetneq B$ and that $f:B\to A$ is a bijection.  Take $x_{0}\in B\setminus A$, and define a sequence recursively by $x_{k+1}=f(x_{k})$.  It is easy to prove that this sequence never repeats, and so $B$ must contain a copy of $\mathbb{N}$ and thus be infinite.

Comment: Why never repeats?

Comment: Define a sequence sets recursively: $A_0=B $ and $ A_{k+1}=f [A_{k}] $. Then the set $\{A_{k}\setminus A_{k+1}\vert k\in\mathbb {N}\}\cup\left\{\bigcap_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k\right\} $ is a partition of $ B $, with $ x_k\in A_k $.

Comment: Easy but hardly obvious! :-)